# Is there a way to use both external volume keys on an android device pressed together for a 3rd unique output?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a counting app which uses the external volume keys for counting up and down. But I would like to use both keys pressed together for a 3rd unique output, like as a reset button. is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity. Try below code for Volume UP + Volume DOWN. You can reduce PRESS_INTERVAL to get effect like both buttons are pressed at the same time. Hope This Helps!

```
private static final int PRESS_INTERVAL = 500;
private long mUpKeyEventTime = 0;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN== event.getKeyCode()) {            
            if ((event.getEventTime() - mUpKeyEventTime) < PRESS_INTERVAL) {
                // This is to check if Volume UP key and Volume DOWN key are pressed at the same time.
                // Do the Task. Here You can add logic to do whatever you like
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP == keyCode){
            mUpKeyEventTime = event.getEventTime();
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```